# CSS Flex - how do I make div content scrollable?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to create a sidebar which has 2 boxes.  Each box can contain any number of list items(could be hundreds of items), but it's likely that the first will contain only a few items, and the second will contain many more.

I have the following (created in ReactJS):

```
<div class="drawer">
  <div class="drawerContainer">
    <div class="sideboxWrapper">
      <SideBox header="Box 1" />
      <SideBox header="Box 2" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Each SideBox generates the following structure:

```
<div class="sidebox">
  <h2 class="boxheader">{header}</h2>
  <div class="boxContent">
    <ul class="sideboxList">
      <li class="listItemText listItemTextCurrent">Item 1</li>
      <li class="listItemText listItemTextCurrent">Item 2</li>
       ... more items ...
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

So, first of all, I want the boxes to fill the sidebar, but not overflow it.  If the boxes are short enough to both fit, then they should both take up as much space as they need, and any remaining space is left blank.  If they don't both fit, then they should take up the available space, and the boxContent div should become scrollable.

```
.drawer {
    flex: 0 0 240px;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    padding: 10px 0;
}

.drawerContainer {
    height: inherit;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
}

.sideboxWrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: inherit;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.sidebox {
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 0px;
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-shrink: 1;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.boxContent {
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

The problem I'm having is that when one of the lists is very long, the `sideboxes` just expand to fit it, even if that means going outside the `sideboxWrapper` (the overflow is hidden, so the part of the `sidebox` outside the `sideboxWrapper` can't be read). What I want to happen is that the flex layout arranges the `sideboxes` to fit inside the `sideboxWrapper`, and then the `boxheaders` are shown and the `boxContent` is resized (with scrollbars) to fit within the remaining space.  So, a long list will have scrollbars.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Could you please add a working code snippet? I had difficulty understanding the exact body structure and cannot illustrate.

Comment: Thanks.  @G-Cyrillus has given me a working solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is what could be your CSS , I added border so you can see where stands some of your boxes. Using flexbox on so many levels requires to follow clearly what you are doing and see where flex is avalaible and needed.

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.drawer {
  width: 240px;/* without a flex parent that works too */
  height: 100vh;/* example for a full screen height */
  overflow-y: hidden;
  padding: 10px 0;
  border: solid;
}

.drawerContainer {
  height: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.sideboxWrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  border: solid green;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.sidebox {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 0px;
  flex-basis: 50%;/* make it half */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 0;/* what is needed */
}

.boxContent {
  flex-grow: 1;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  This mostly solves it.  The only issue now is that if one box is quite small (only a few items) it still takes up 50% of the space.  Is there a way to avoid that?  If not, I think this is close enough!  Thanks for your help.

Comment: just commented about another question on the wrong place. For this, set flex-grow and overflow to the one you wish to see shrinking the other one and probably flex-shrink:1 to the one supposed to be small not showing a scrollbar